# UI design is not working(CSS is not loading)

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

I developed a web application having LDAP authentication. So when I load my login page for the initial time, it won't take any CSS styles and when I login to the system, the inner page designes are perfectly OK. And when I logout, it navigates to login page and now the login page design is perfectly ok and it loads all the CSS files perfectly.

If I clear the history and refresh the login page, the login page won't load perfectly. The CSS files will not load perfectly.

Before integrating LDAP to the application, it works perfectly for all the time.

Can anybody come up with a solution, please?

setting in webconfig

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="syslogin.aspx" name="adAuthCookie" timeout="10" path="/">
  </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
```

updated webconfig

```
<location path="img">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

I wrote this code to access the image from the folder "img" which I set as background of a div and it's actually the logo. But it won't work.

Regards,

Sivajith

Comment: Clearly your CSS files are subject to authorization, please post more configuration information if you want more help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `<location>` Rule in your web.config to allow anonymous users to your static ressources, if all your styles, scripts, images etc. are in the `/static` directory, use:

```
<location path="/static">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: i got error on this when i set this and the error is like authorization is not valid at this place

Comment: Please refer to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.85).aspx) location should be under `<configuration>` and should contain `<system.web>`

Comment: i wrote all the styles to login page and now it works fine...except for the images

Comment: in your question you refer to CSS, where are you stylesheets in `/img`?

Comment: i removed the style sheet and wrote all the css styles with in the page page and it works fine but the image (logo) is missing yet.